Better way to block IP Addresses with an Azure VM
I am using Azure for my virtual machines and it gives you a way to block IP addresses in the Network Security Group. However this IP list is getting quite long. Is there a better option to do than this in Azure with my VM?


What are you trying to achieve by blocking individual IPs? If you're trying to subvert an attack (or similar), then this isn't a sensible approach... Can you reverse this and permit only a small set of IPs / ranges?

I can, but wouldnt that block maybe legit traffic.  These IPs are all around the world in other countries mostly.  I have blocked sets before but I try to stray away from that because of legit users.

If this is intended to be a public service, then blocking individual IPs like this is a bad approach that will consume a lot of manual time... You'd be much better off looking for automated tools, or building rate limits into your service.

Maybe, the issue is we have events that could be coming from one IP address that gets thousands of hits a second.  Those are legit requests, a hacker who is maybe hitting our site with 100 requests a second wouldn't be.  Once we notice a hacker or DOS attack we just lock down that IP.  I am not sure Azure has anything to help with all this.

I'm not sure I'd use "Hacker" and "Denial of Service" to refer to unknown requests measuring an order of magnitude less than a single legitimate user...(?) There are plenty of tools out there (from Azure, CloudFlare, etc...) to handle DDoS situations, but from what you've shared with us so far, they're also not likely to consider this traffic problematic.

Depending on what's going on (it's very hard to read into a situation with this little information), you may be much better off with rate limits (as above), and lower limits / a quick-exit for unauthenticated requests... is CPU time the problem? bandwidth? more information would certainly help us help you!

There are hackers that try to screenscrap our system, and we see SQL injections happening from outside countries.  We would love to block these guys outside of a long IP string.
